# ConstraintLayout won't size correctly (in practice)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm quite new to using constraint layouts and I'm having issues with the layout sizing, I want it to be responsive so I won't have to make 10 more layouts for different screen sizes. In the layout editor, everything looks perfect on different sizes but in practice, it doesn't.

I've made some research and tried using guidelines, chains, and non-hard-coded sizes,layout_weight, I also attached at least 3 constraints for each element, but it still doesn't help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bubble3d"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="@string/BUTTON_PLAY"
        android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dispName"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bubble3d"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="@string/BUTTON_SETTINGS"
        android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnStats" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStats"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bubble3d"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="@string/BUTTON_STATS"
        android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnSettings"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnPlay" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/worddart" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:scaleX="0.7"
        android:scaleY="0.7"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/proficon_crab"
        app:civ_border_color="#03A9F4"
        app:civ_border_width="12dp"
        app:civ_fill_color="#03A9F4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.493"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dispName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="AnonCrab_c343d"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circleImageView" />


    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnSettings"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.815" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and also added this to styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
</style>
```

[This is how it's supposed to look on Pixel2 screen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hftwV6nyhOv2M3ziUGeBUnGQN_bAg3U3/view?usp=sharing)

[and this is how it looks on my Nexus 5 (almost the same size as pixel2)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YIX2vmI8bsjYU-3NiKWEoasOGU48gp5I/view?usp=sharing)

as you can see horizontally-wise, everything is ok, but vertically, not really, the google sign in button slips out and spacings are different.
Any help would really be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that you are not using hardcoded sizes for your view, but please notice that you are using them as margins.

**Try to use it like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:text="BUTTON_PLAY"
    android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnStats"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dispName" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:text="BUTTON_SETTINGS"
    android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/sign_in_button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnPlay"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnStats" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStats"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:text="BUTTON_STATS"
    android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnSettings"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnPlay"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnPlay" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="313dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dispName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circleImageView"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleX="0.7"
    android:scaleY="0.7"
    android:src="@drawable/proficon_crab"
    app:civ_border_color="#03A9F4"
    app:civ_border_width="12dp"
    app:civ_fill_color="#03A9F4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dispName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="AnonCrab_c343d"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnPlay"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />


<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnSettings" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**It will look like this:**

[image]

This is a picture from the layout editor because this is just an example, feel free to play with the styles according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Do you know how I can make the buttons bigger (vertically) without the text changing in size? I tried using padding but it doesn't change anything, and using scaleY stretches the text...

Comment: Maybe add horizontally guidelines between the buttons and chain every button to 2 guidelines